# How to detect where strings begin in Lua Bytecode? (using C#)

Tags: c#, string, lua, bytecode

How to detect where strings begin in Lua Bytecode using C#?
I would like to list all the strings in a Lua Bytecode file.

Comment: I think you'd have to write some portion of a LUA compiler to ensure you were finding strings 100% correctly.  You could use regular expressions, but I'm sure there are some cases where they would fail (e.g. multi-line strings)

Comment: @Merl: The OP said "bytecode", not "source code". RegExp's are not that useful with binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the file. There are no special markers. See the source code in [lundump.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lundump.c.html).

Comment: Reproduce what lundump.c does, skipping the data you don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the reference to the same statement on LUA's site, but here is a quote I found elsewhere:

> there is no official
>   specification of the Lua virtual machine instruction set, there is no need for one; the only
>   official specification is of the Lua language

This document does try to break up the instruction set and provide a pseudo-spec from reverse engineering:

http://luaforge.net/docman/index.php?group_id=83&selected_doc_group_id=102&language_id=1

In that doc, it says that strings are constants attached to each function (w/ the exception of globals, which are in a table).

Comment: The link in the answer is dead: https://web.archive.org/web/20100816073843/http://luaforge.net/docman/index.php?group_id=83&selected_doc_group_id=102&language_id=1

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, literal strings are stored in bytecode in the same format as they are in sourcecode- that is, "sometexthere". However, I suggest that you just compile a Lua file with nothing but a function with a string returned and see what it looks like in bytecode.

Comment: This is not correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660387/is-it-possible-to-change-strings-content-and-size-in-lua-bytecode-so-that-it-wi/3661621#3661621